# Adding JsStore in angular 6 library can't resolve file-loader

Tags: angular6, indexeddb

I am using JsStore with angular 6 and I am getting this error when try to import it with file-loader
 " import * as workerPath from 'file-loader?name=scripts/[name].[hash].js!jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.js' ".

It show cannot find module 'file-loader?name=scripts/[name].[hash].js!jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.js'.

Adding the extra folder with worker.d.ts file doesn't help in angular library generated with the new 'ng generate library' because the library use roll-up instead of web-pack and doesnt has a file-loader. Could you suggest me another way to import jsstore.worker.js, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approach to do it -

You can copy the jsstore script in a folder then supply the path of the worker to jsstore instance.

e.g -

var con = new JsStore.Instance(new Worker('path of the jsstore worker script'));

But it would be better if we can include the script directly into the code, so that webpack or any other module bundler can take care of everything. We need to find a way to do it.

Another approach would be to run jsstore without worker (i dont recommend it, as it is slower). Check out the example - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/tree/master/examples/ts%20without%20worker

Hope this helps.